# Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode

Tags: xcode

Details

Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode.
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: 5
Failure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform: >. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
User Info: {
    DVTDeviceDescription = "\Ud83d\Udcf1";
}